# Selecting poles in complex plane

Tags: list-manipulation, complex

I have list of poles listed in a vector, poles `list = {.....}`. They are shown in the figure attached. To use Cauchy’s residue theorem, I would like to select only the poles of the shaded area in the figure. How can I do that in Mathematica?

[image: complex plane with poles]

Comment: This question is highly underspecified. What are you trying to do? Pick out the desired poles from a list? Perform a contour integral that surrounds those poles? Evaluate the residues at those poles? All we have is a drawn figure, and it's impossible to understand what exactly you want to do in *Mathematica*. Please edit your post by clicking the grey edit button below your post and add more information.

Comment: Just picking the poles from a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say the list is in the form of a list of pole locations (i.e., complex numbers). Call the list z. Then select those that fulfill the criteria specified by the line in the picture: those that have imaginary parts positive and also those with zero imaginary and positive real. Hence:

```
z = Table[i + j I, {i, -5, 5}, {j, -5, 5}] // Flatten
Select[z, Im[#] > 0 || (Im[#] == 0 && Re[#] > 0) &]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.